# How can I let other person to remote login to my desktop

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I am running Ubuntu 8.04. How can I configure my environment so that another user can log in to my machine and see my desktop and X programs (e.g. firefox) (i.e. ssh won't work for me).

Thank you.

Comment: you want them to see your desktop (eg VNC screen sharing), or you want them to see their own desktop (eg "multiseat" or "terminal server" or "remote X session")?

Answer (score 3):

For simple screen sharing, use vnc. (RealVNC download)

Otherwise (assuming Windows OS), for actual logging into a new session, you would configure a new account with remote desktop privileges and enable the Remote Desktop service (previously known as MS terminal services)

Comment: he's using ubuntu, so MS terminal services/remote desktop aren't really applicable.  there are X-windows equivalents, tho.

Answer (score 2):

On the server:

```
System->Preferences->Remote Desktop
```

tick 'Allow users to view/control your desktop',
choose password etc

Then use

```
Applications->Internet->Remote Desktop Viewer
```

on the client to connect. If on win you can use normal vncviewer, since remote desktop uses a VNC on Ubuntu.